# Legal cover up for incarcerating people in S.T.A.R. Labs

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

AFAIK, incarcerating people randomly in cells is highly illegal. However, we find in the 2014 CW series "The Flash" that all metahumans they met, were put in prison cells in the used-to-be particle accelerator.

I am not highly experienced with the comics but is there at least an attempt to cover this legally? I mean there are cops (detective West and Thawne) that are aware of the existence of the jail and are totally cool with it, they're like "Oh you're holding people in there without food or water or even a f****ng window, that's cool, Batman gives them to Arkham and they end up back in the street, this is more efficient."

The series doesn't even bother showing human treatment to prisoners, and unless a metahuman is needed for a favor, he remains in a 1m x 1m cell to die.

[image]

My TL;DR question is: Is there a legal cover for this "jail" in The Flash universe. And is it a comics thing, or something the series came up with.

Comment: Since Wells seems to plan to use the meta-villains as tools when needed, he probably feeds them.

Comment: @Taladris They could've shown him once or cisco bringing food to them, they seem to work from 9-5 then go home as if no one is held against his will inside an exploded particle accelerator.

Comment: The usual thing: we don't see characters going to toilets, but it doesn't mean they never go. And, as you say in the question, it doesn't fit with the characters to let them starve to death (why not simply kill them). Also, there is no evidence from the show but I am not sure that people in StarLabs work on a 9-5 basis (that's definitely not how most real life academics work).

Comment: @Taladris I agree, however they should've at least shown it once to prove it, that's not much to ask. But truly that's the least of my worries in this series, there are larger and more important holes in the plot that reduce the fun I'm having while watching it sadly.

Comment: They filmed such a food delivery scene actually, but it was ultimately deleted: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BUO8K2WjW5c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not something from the comics, by the time the Flash (the one depicted in the show) was active, supervillains had been active in DC comics for a while.  So legal restraint of them was already in place, it wasn't a new problem that lacked solutions.

In the show, it's not legal at all.  Joe and Thawne would only go along with it because it's the only real solution, and they're not acting in any official police capacity when it comes to the Flash or the jailing of metahumans.  The *Arrow/Flash* universe was a normal, grounded universe (like real life) until the particle accelerator accident, restraining metahumans wasn't a thing that anyone had to do until that happened.  No normal jail could hold most of the metahumans that are locked up there.  Even ARGUS would be at a loss to provide adequate facilities, so we haven't seen them work with Lyla on a solution.